# Is it safe to change the language ISO code on a "Production" Magento installation?

Tags: language, migration, magento-1.5.1

We are required to migrate a Magento site to OpenCart and to do so, the tool requires that both sites' multilingual implementation have the same ISO codes.

It seems though that for some reason in the Magento installation, instead of the ISO code for the setting they used the full language name. (i.e. instead of "en_US" they used "english")

The question is, should we correct this on the the Magento production installation, and if we do, what problems should we expect?

Any suggestion is welcomes.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who may bump on this question in the future. After trial, there was no apparent side effects to the normal operation of the website. So I assume it is safe enough as long there is no plugin that is directly connected to those settings.